# FOSElasticaBundle for symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm looking to integrate the FOSElasticaBundle into my symfony 3 project. Currently this bundle doesn't support symfony 3. I was ondering what I could do to still implement it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems is not yet tagged a valid release for using it via packagist. [See this issue on github](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/issues/1057).

The release `dev-master / 3.2.x-dev` seems already compliant with symfony3.

I successfully installed this bundle on a symfony3 installation with the command :

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle dev-master
```

Hope this help